# Webstorm External Merge tool

Tags: webstorm, tortoisegit, tortoisegitmerge

I'm trying to use an external merge tool (Tortoise Git) whitin Webstorm, but I encountered a problem. I can figure out how to replace the following placeholders in the "Parameters" input: $LOCAL, $REMOTE, $BASE and $MERGED.

[image]

As you can see I have %1 %2 %3 %4 which I must replace somehow. I've tryed with 
`$LOCAL $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED`

but it didn't work. Can anybody help?

**EDIT**

The next problem is that when I encounter a conflict, TortoiseGit doesn't seems to find the files needed so I can process the merge.
[image]

Here I have a conflict with index.html and I press "Merge".

[image]

Here TorgoiseGit ask me for the files.

So here I'm asking, how to configure WebStorm so TortoiseGit find these files automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "I **must** replace somehow" ? As far as I'm aware the parameters meant to be `%1`, `%2`, `%3` and `%4` and not `$LOCAL` etc

Comment: %1 %2 %3 %4 it's not working. I'm wondering should I rearange the order or what?

Comment: Well .. it should be in order and using the syntax that Tortoise Git accepts. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegitmerge/tme-automation.html (check command line parameters of actual program anyway) . Based on that it should be something like `/mine:"%1" /theirs:"%2" ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is caused by incorrect options escaping in WebStorm ([IDEA-156227](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-156227)). I can suggest the following workaround:

- create a new .bat file (C:\tortoise_launcher.bat, for example) with the following content:

> start "" "C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe"
>   -base:%1 -mine:%2 -theirs:%3 -merged:%4

- change Settings | Tools | Diff | External Diff Tools as follows:

> ```
> Path to executable: cmd.exe
> Parameters: /C C:\tortoise_launcher.bat %3 %1 %2 %4
> ```

This configuration works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

The Parameters may be:

```
/theirs:"%1" /mine:"%2" /base:"%3" /merged:"%4" /theirsname:"Local changes" /minename:"Server content" /basename:"BASE" /mergedname:"output"
```

(cf. [TortoiseGitMerge Command Line Switches](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegitmerge/tme-automation.html#tme-automation-1-table))

This is my testing:

```
TortoiseGitMerge.exe /theirs:"D:\left.txt" /mine:"D:\right.txt" /base:"D:\base.txt" /merged:"D:\output.txt" /theirsname:"Local changes" /minename:"Server content" /basename:"BASE" /mergedname:"output"
```

Something like this:

[image]

---

Add this reg will allow you to see the actual command line:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseGitMerge]
"Debug"=dword:00000001
```

Perhaps help to figure something out. It will show a message box, something like this:

[image]

Comment: I eddited my question, could you check it out? Thanks.

Comment: what if drop the `"` ? I mean `/theirs:"%1"` -> `/theirs:%1`.